# DFGUI (Kivy) has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, kivy

So i've been trying to using dfgui to display my pandas data into kivy.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import dfgui
import pandas as pd


class Display(FloatLayout):
    def data(self):
        df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
        dfgui.show(df)

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Display()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

kivy file

```
<Display>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .62,.91,.968,1
        Rectangle:
            pos : self.pos
            size : self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"DFGUI"
            font_size:30
            color: 1,.984,.58
            pos_hint:{"y":0.4}
            bold:True

        Button:
            text:"Data"
            on_press: root.data()
            size_hint: 0.1,0.1
```

Error:

```
 
 AttributeError: module 'dfgui' has no attribute 'show'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

it shows that dfgui doesn't have show attribute. So what should I use? Thanks for helping. Have a good day!!

Comment: You should debug this by trying to work out why dfgui doesn't have a `show` attribute. For a start, does it work if you delete all the code except `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')` and `dfgui.show(df)`? Also check what is the value of `dfgui.__file__`, is there any chance you've imported the wrong thing?

Comment: Have you installed the [requirements](https://github.com/bluenote10/PandasDataFrameGUI#requirements)?